# Does cost varies for each edge location using cloud front or s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Can the cost be varied for using CloudFront and s3 bucket at each location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cost  does vary for different regions in S3 based on data transfer across regions. You can choose any AWS region that is geographically close to you to optimize latency, minimize costs, or address regulatory requirements. For example, if you reside in Europe, you might find it advantageous to create buckets in the EU (Ireland) or EU (Frankfurt) regions.

It varies in case of cloudfront too based on regional data transfer. Here you can find pricing based on regions

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: Thank you this is useful one